# The View got Pixelated during Animation to Tilt

Tags: java, android, android-animation

The view got pixilated during animation I just wanted to attain a little tilt while the I try to scroll. I am using the Universal-Image-Library to hanle the animation. I'd like to attain a 3D look when tilting the view.

The first picture, is what I want.[image]

---

But this picture below, I what I have. The *View* below got pixilated.

[image]

```
  private void rotateLeftFrag(View af) {


        if (af != null) {
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(af, "rotationY", 5, 0)
                    .setDuration(100).start();
                  }
    }
```

---

```
ObjectAnimator com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(Object target, String 
                                   propertyName, float... values)
```

Are there any resolve to this to attain smooth animation or titling of the view? Thanks

**Update:**

```
            float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            af.setCameraDistance(density * scale);
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(af, "rotationY", .5f, 0).setDuration(500).start();
```

Comment: Just a thought, but did you looked at the docs for the `View.setRotationY()` and `View.setCameraDistance()` methods?

Comment: I got some experiment with `prop-animation`. But I am not sure if the `View.setRotation` diff. from my code, also I have not yet checked the `setCameraDistance`. Please give me one sec.

Comment: hmmm, I am confused on with `setCamera`, the `setRotation` is the same. Would you like me to try those two together? `float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
         af.setCameraDistance(1280 * scale);`

Comment: Did you ever solve the issue? I'm also interested in this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this video could help you:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMcu35-tVls

At 2:10 the guy talks about adding 1 extra transparent pixel to each side of a rotating rectangle. That should help smoothing out the edges because they would be inside the rectangle, not on the border.

Link to the source code is below the video.

In case you can't see it:
http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/CardFlip.zip

Class you want to see is CardView, method bitmapWithBorder:

```
private static final int ANTIALIAS_BORDER = 1;

/**
 *  Adding a 1 pixel transparent border around the bitmap can be used to
 *  anti-alias the image as it rotates.
 */
private BitmapDrawable bitmapWithBorder(BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable) {
    Bitmap bitmapWithBorder = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() +
            ANTIALIAS_BORDER * 2, bitmapDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight() + ANTIALIAS_BORDER * 2,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapWithBorder);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap(), ANTIALIAS_BORDER, ANTIALIAS_BORDER, null);
    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapWithBorder);
}
```

Comment: Please include your source.

Comment: I am using the whole layout to animate not just the image. Basing from your solution how I can use it in an activity view or whole xml without it being pixilated? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try to turn off hardware rendering

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    mHeaderImage.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```